# Convergence of the following series(hypergeomteric)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, power-series

It is required to find the values of x for which the series whose terms are given by $$ a_n=\frac{1.3.5...(2n-1)}{2.4.6...(2n)}x^n$$

I’m new to this type of series( I don’t see how radio test or root test can be used here). Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{1.3.5....(2n-1)}{2.4.6 . . .2n}=\frac{n!}{(2^n.n!)^2}=\frac{
1}{2^{2n}.n!}$$

So if $x<1$ the series converges to 0.